# Manipulating DOM elements with jQuery and chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Playing around with jQuery a bit (sorry, complete noob) I was wondering why this does not work. Maybe I'm not getting the way chaining, context and DOM manipulation works, but I'm just curious. Here it goes:

```
$("#myDiv")
    .append("h3")
    .append("a")
    .attr("href", "http://example.com")
    .text("Click here")
    .end();
```

What I would expect to happen:

- Select `#myDiv`
- Insert an H3 inside it
- Then inside the H3, insert an A tag
- Set the A tag's HREF attribute to a URL
- And then set the A tag's text to "Click Here"

Instead my page's markup seems to get completely screwed up, although I can't see the dynamic DOM so I'm not sure what's happening. Am I reading the jQuery documentation wrong?

Comment: .end() is unnecessary as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be

```
$("#myDiv")
    .append("<h3>").children('h3:last')
    .append("<a>").children('a:last')
    .attr("href", "http://example.com")
    .text("Click here")
```

Each method returns the original jQuery object on which it was executed (*except for the [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) ones like `find`, `children` etc*) so you can continue working on them.

I completely removed the `.end()` since that is only useful if you use the traversing methods that alter the jQuery object.

---

So your original one, (*besides the error that html in append needs tags if you want to add tags*) would append a `h3` to the `#myDiv`, then append an `a` again to the `#div`, then set an attribute `href` to the `#myDiv` and finally sets its text - *the `#myDivs` text ;)*.

Everything would be done on the `#myDiv`.

Comment: @sakuntala Additionally, you can see the updated DOM using Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) for FireFox.

Comment: or Developer Tools in Chrome...  I'm sure Safari and IE have something too

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between your approach and Sime's answer below? He references the tags directly by enclosing them in the `$()` call... how does that work?

Comment: You can pass html to the jquery method ( `$` ) and it will convert it to valid in-memory nodes, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2  @Šime uses new calls to the jquery function, the `$()` to create elements on the fly and use the returned value as parameter to the previous command. So he is calling a method and passing as arguments the returns of another method .. etc.. So he is not really chaining many things.. It is an alternative way to accomplish the same thing, but not through chaining..

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation and the help. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$('#myDiv')
    .append($('<h3>')
        .append($('<a>')
            .text('Click here')
            .attr('href', 'http://example.com')));
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HNMET/1/

Notice that the DOM is manipulated upon **only once** (= when the H3 element is appended to the DIV).

---

Since the above code is a bit tricky (which makes it a bit confusing I guess), I've broken it down into 3 lines. Note, this is practically the same code, I've only added two "helper" variables to make it more readable:

```
var anchor, h3;

anchor = $('<a>').text('Click here').attr('href', 'http://example.com');
h3 = $('<h3>').append( anchor );
$('#myDiv').append( h3 );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HNMET/11/

Comment: My god, it's full of stars. That's such a useful tool, thank you very much!!

Comment: By the way, sorry I can't vote your answer up but this thing won't let me :\

Comment: Thank you again, that was very enlightening. I'm still trying to learn though this stuff.